# any other option for php header in jquery

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui

do we have any other option to open url in another window like jquery dialog ui or something else which will have same functionality like PHP's header

```
header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use javascript open method `window.open(URL)`

For example `window.open('http://stackoverflow.com','','width=400,height=600')`

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit difficult to understand what you're asking, but does this do what you need?

```html
<a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com/" target="_blank">Open SO in a new window.</a>
```